# best way to build an android alarm clock

Tags: android

I am building an alarm clock app for android as my first go at an app. All my activities, views and a nice ui are ready.
My problem is that I just can't decide which is the best way to start each alarm.

As far as I can see, I have two options:

Option 1 - I can use android's built in AlarmManager to manage the alarm.
But if I do so, then how can I store the different alarm types?
What I mean is: there are four alarm types in my app: Standard, math, puzzle anf bar code scanner.
So, when the alarm goes off, I need it to know which dismiss activity to show.

My biggest worry is that I have been reading that some manufacturers disable the built in alarm manager such as HTC and a few others.

Option 2 - Store all the alarms in a database that my app will create, and have my app permanently running in the background.
But I feel this is excessive and wil use to many resources.

Can anyone Point me in the right direction? I want the app to work perfectly on every device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Option 1 . I can use androids built in alarm manager to manage the alarm

This is the only sensible solution.

> But if I do this then how can I store the different alarn types

Have an extra in the `Intent` in your `PendingIntent` for `AlarmManager` that indicates what specifically should be done when the alarm goes off.

> My biggest worry is that I have been reading that some manufatures disable the built in alarm manager such as HTC and a frw others.

I am not aware of HTC messing with `AlarmManager` -- if you have a link to that, I'd love to see it. SONY, when the device is in STAMINA mode, will treat `_WAKEUP` alarms the same as their non-`_WAKEUP` counterparts. However, the user has to opt into STAMINA mode and can add apps to a whitelist to be left alone.

> Store all the alarms in a database that my app will create and have my app permanently running in the background

Since your app cannot be permanently running in the background, this will not work well.